# ng-repeat in ng-repeat, not correct display

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two game configuration in my DB, I would like to display the number of case of the two games with Angular.

```
Game.create({
   name : 'Iphone 5S',
   info : '',
   price : 2,
   cases : 25  
}, {
   name : 'Iphone 4',
   info : '',
   price : 5,
   cases : 20
});
```

I make this :

```
<div ng-repeat="game in games">
    <ul ng-repeat="i in getTimes(game.cases) track by $index">
            //game.cases = 25, already is ok
            <button type="button" class="btn">O</button>            
    </ul>
</div>
```

My function `getTimes`:

```
$scope.getTimes=function(n){
    return new Array(n);
};
```

Why I have only one button for each game?
I would like 25 button for the `game1` and 20 for the `game2`.

Comment: It should be fine. Do you see any errors in your console? Also side note ul can only have li as its immediate child.

Comment: Already is ok in the console :/
When i put an alert in my getTimes function i have 25 to. :/

Comment: What i am saying you should just have as many number of buttons as specified in the cases. Issue is elsewhere. Please show us a demo showcasing the issue (While doing that there is a very good chance you will find out the issue yourself).

Comment: Inside the `getTimes` function, please check `typeof n` to see what datatype it has.

Comment: That is a good point from @JLRishe. Your `Game.create` which transforms the viewmodel may be converting it to string or something, which would just end up creating array with just one item.

Comment: I think it's the String, your right, i try

Comment: The problem is fixed, thank. you can make an answer if you want i valide !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the value you use to create the array is a number:

```
$scope.getTimes=function(n){
    return new Array(+n);
};
```

otherwise it will create a size-1 array with the value that you pass in.

Comment: Thank's it work !
Can i have your opinon for my last answer ?